# Heart Beat line for splash screen

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i want to add heart beat horizontal line for splash screen, it will start animating from one side and go all the way to other if the initial data is still not loaded it will continue animation

i tried below code but its only pulse kinda animation

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SpritePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Animation<double> _animation;

  SpritePainter(this._animation) : super(repaint: _animation);

  void circle(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, double value) {
    double opacity = (1.0 - (value / 4.0)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    Color color = Color.fromRGBO(0, 117, 194, opacity);

    double size = rect.width / 2;
    double area = size * size;
    double radius = sqrt(area * value / 4);

    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawCircle(rect.center, radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);

    for (int wave = 3; wave >= 0; wave--) {
      circle(canvas, rect, wave + _animation.value);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(SpritePainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class SpriteDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SpriteDemoState createState() => SpriteDemoState();
}

class SpriteDemoState extends State<SpriteDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
    );
    //_startAnimation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startAnimation() {
    _controller
      ..stop()
      ..reset()
      ..repeat(period: const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Pulse')),
      body: CustomPaint(
        painter: SpritePainter(_controller),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _startAnimation,
        child: new Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: SpriteDemo(),
    ),
  );
}
```

I want it to start(animate) from center left and go all the way to right just like in image

[image: Heart beat line example]

Comment: btw, seems you aren't following the correct one. you might start with custom Paint , or rive